# C++ Overloaded operator is not exported to dll

Tags: c++, dllimport, mingw-w64, dllexport

I'm creating this simple struct (Windows 10, g++10.2 Mingw-64):

```
#ifndef GEARSETDATA_H
#define GEARSETDATA_H

#include "Helpers_global.h"

#include <cmath>

namespace Helpers
{

template<class T>
struct HELPERS_EXPORT GearSetData
{
public:
    T pinion, wheel;
    GearSetData(const T &pinion = T(), const T &wheel = T()): pinion(pinion), wheel(wheel)
    {
    }
};

template<class T>
HELPERS_EXPORT bool operator==(const GearSetData<T> &gearSetData1, const GearSetData<T> &gearSetData2)
{
    return ((std::abs(gearSetData1.pinion - gearSetData2.pinion) < 1.0e-9) && (std::abs(gearSetData1.wheel - gearSetData2.wheel) < 1.0e-9));
}

}

#endif // GEARSETDATA_H
```

It is using the definitions from the file "Helpers_global.h":

```
#ifndef HELPERS_GLOBAL_H
#define HELPERS_GLOBAL_H

#if defined(_MSC_VER) || defined(WIN64) || defined(_WIN64) || defined(__WIN64__) || defined(WIN32) || defined(_WIN32) || defined(__WIN32__) || defined(__NT__)
#  define DECL_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
#  define DECL_IMPORT __declspec(dllimport)
#else
#  define DECL_EXPORT     __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#  define DECL_IMPORT     __attribute__((visibility("default")))
#endif

#if defined(HELPERS_LIBRARY)
#  define HELPERS_EXPORT DECL_EXPORT
#else
#  define HELPERS_EXPORT DECL_IMPORT
#endif

#endif // HELPERS_GLOBAL_H
```

The problem I have is, that the struct itself is exported as expexcted, the operator == however is not. During the compilation I get the following error message.

> error: function 'bool Helpers::operator==(const Helpers::GearSetData&, const Helpers::GearSetData&)' definition is marked dllimport

If I change HELPERS_EXPORT to DECL_EXPORT for the operator it compiles sucessfully.

Do you have any idea why the struct is exported as expected and the operator is not? And why does it work is work when I change the "export keyword"?

Comment: A DLL can contain functions, but not function templates. A function template is not a function. A specific instantiation of a function template is a function.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The struct is exported, the operator is not. Even if I use a specific instantiation I get the same error message.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "struct is exported"? A DLL contains functions, not structs. You cannot export a function template. Please show how you export  a specific instantiation.

Comment: Anyway the compilation error says that you cannot apply dllimport to a function *definition*, only to a declaration that is not a definition. It is unrelated to templates, bit you shouldn't try to export templates, it makes no sense.

Comment: As you may have noticed, I'm pretty new to c++ programming. Anyway, I solved my problem by removing the export statement from the operator definition. Now, everything works as expected. Thank you very much fpr your help!